# Saving to .mp4 file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, video, mp4, video-processing, avi

I'm editing all frames of an existing mp4 video in MATLAB (doing it in a for loop).
After I'm done editing, I want to save the new set of frames to a new output video file, but in mp4 rather than .avi (that seems to be the default).
I thought changing the filename extension is sufficient, but apparently it's not.
Any ideas?

```
newVid = VideoWriter(outputfilename);
newVid.FrameRate = fps;
newVid.Quality = 100;
open(newVid)
for...
writeVideo(newVid,imgs{i})%within the for loop saving one frame at a time
end
close(newVid)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Renaming the file is not sufficient.  You also need to specify the codec you want.  In your case, you need to include an additional parameter into the `VideoWriter` constructor that consists of the codec you want to use as a MATLAB 
 string.  In your case, specify `'MPEG-4'`:

```
newVid = VideoWriter(outputfilename, 'MPEG-4'); % New
newVid.FrameRate = fps;
newVid.Quality = 100;
open(newVid);
for ...
% Rest of your code here
```

BTW, have a look at the documentation in the future.  It clearly shows you what to do if you want to save to a new format, and not AVI: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html#input_argument_d0e1094625

Comment: thanks! I looked at the documentation actually but wasn't clear exactly where does the mpeg4 come in.

Comment: @guyts No problem!  I'll admit that it's a bit confusing.  I just know from experience that what you do above is what you need to do :).

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a profile argument to matlab's videowriter.

From Matlab [Help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.htm), `VideoWriter(filename,profile)` creates a VideoWriter object and applies a set of properties tailored to a specific file format (such as 'MPEG-4' or 'Uncompressed AVI').

In your case, you need to pass the string `MPEG-4` to the profile argument.